# How to test angular 2 component with nested components inside with their own dependencies ? (TestBed.configureTestingModule)

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have a component A that use a component B,c,D in its template:

```
###template-compA.html

    <comp-b></comp-b>
    <comp-c [myinput]="obj.myinput"></comp-c>
    <comp-d ></comp-d>
```

...etc

To simplify, let's say their is only one directive in component A:

```
 ###template-compA.html

    <comp-b></comp-b>
```

My comp-b has its own dependencies (services or other comp).

If I want to test comp-a this way:

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    declarations: [comp-A],
    imports: [ReactiveFormsModule],
}).overrideComponent(FAQListComponent, {
    set: {
    providers: [
        { provide: comp-AService, useValue: comp-AListSVC }
    ]
    }
})
    .compileComponents();
```

it would not work properly. So I do:

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    declarations: [comp-A, comp-B],
    imports: [ReactiveFormsModule],
}).overrideComponent(FAQListComponent, {
    set: {
    providers: [
        { provide: comp-AService, useValue: comp-AListSVC }
    ]
    }
})
    .compileComponents();
```

It doesn't work also because comp-b doesn't have its own dependencies. And here I am confused, how can I do unit test if I have to import and remock all others components every single time ? It looks like a very big amount of work. Is there another way? What would be the best practice to test component with nested componentS that have their own dependencies ?

Thanks a lot,

Stéphane.

Comment: Have you tried `schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]`? https://blog.nrwl.io/essential-angular-testing-192315f8be9b#.vygkcekn0

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you don't need to reference `comp-b` in any way in your tests you can add `schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA] or [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]` to your `TestBed` configuration or override the `comp-A`'s template and remove the tag for `comp-b`

If you do need to reference `comp-b` you may not need to provide it's dependencies specifically in an override.

Setting `providers` in `overrideComponent` is only necessary if the dependency is provided in the component itself. (If you have a providers list in `comp-A.ts`)

let's say `comp-b` needs a `comp-AService` and `comp-AService` is being provided in your `comp-A` override, since `comp-b` is a child of `comp-A` it will have `comp-AService` provided for it.

If you are providing these dependencies in your `app.module` or somewhere higher than the component itself you don't need to override. For example if `comp-b` needs `comp-AService` & `someOtherService` which are both being provided in your `app.module` your `TestBed` configuration could look like this:

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [comp-A, comp-B],
  imports: [ReactiveFormsModule],
  providers: [
    { provide: comp-AService, useValue: comp-AListSVC },
    { provide: someOtherService, useValue: someOtherServiceSVC }
  ]
})
```

**Edit:**

You can read more about nested component testing here:

https://angular.io/guide/testing-components-scenarios#nested-component-tests

Comment: What does the `NO_ERROR_SCHEMA` do? Does it mean that you want to ignore all children component: https://medium.com/@voorkanter/there-is-a-way-to-ingore-all-child-components-while-unit-testing-a-component-ceddeb56cc0c ?

Comment: @skofgar the `NO_ERROR_SHEMA` tells the compiler to ignore unrecognised elements and attributes. you can read more about using it in tests here:

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/testing/#!#shallow-component-test

I've updated the answer to include this link

Comment: Thanks for adding the info!

Comment: Sure, no worries :)

Answer (score 4):

Following a  @yurzui 's advice:

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [comp-a],
      schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
    })
      .compileComponents();
  }));
```

Answer (score 1):

*It's an old question but this is what I'm currently doing in Angular 9.*

As you'd want to isolate your tested component as much as possible, you can create a function that returns a **fake component** to import, instead of the actual nested component:

```js
  function mockComponent(selector: string) {
    @Component({
      selector,
      template: ''
    })
    class MockValueAccessorComponent {
      // [mock implementation here]
    }

    return MockValueAccessorComponent;
  }
```

And then import it into your TestBed like this:

```js
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    declarations: [
      TestUtils.mockComponent('component-template-to-mock'),
    ]
  });
```